# Get actual pixel coordinates of div after CSS3 transform

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, transform

Is it possible to get the four actual corner coordinates of a `<div />` that has been transformed with CSS3 attributes like `scale`, `skew` and `rotate`?

**Example:**

Before the CSS3 transformation the coordinates are

```
x1y1: 0,0
x1y2: 0,200
x2y1: 200,0
x2yw: 200,200
```

and the div looks like this:

[image: before transformation]

after a little bit of CSS3 magic `transform: skew(10deg, 30deg) rotate(30deg) scale(1, 2);`
it looks like this:

[image: after transformation]

How can I get the coordinates (with javascript) of the actual corners (not the bounding box)? 
Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Mostly sure that there's no API for that yet. Remember that CSS transforms operate in the render land while JS operates in the ECMA/DOM land. Though it'd be a nice addiction.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté I guess I could calculate them from the attributes - where are my math friends :) ?

Comment: Exactly, I've seen a couple of similar questions before and my comment was to apply math. `;)` Though I believe everyone would like to get an API or hack that gives us the correct numbers the lazy way. `:P`

Comment: Brilliant solution! I was racking my head with the math too for too long. this is nice and simple.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

After hours trying to calculate all the transformations and almost giving up desperately I came up with a simple yet genius little hack that makes it **incredibly easy** to get the corner points of the transformed `<div />`

I just added four handles inside the div that are positioned in the corners but invisible to see:

```
<div id="div">
  <div class="handle nw"></div>
  <div class="handle ne"></div>
  <div class="handle se"></div>
  <div class="handle sw"></div>
</div>
```

---

```
.handle {
    background: none;
    height: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 0px;
}   
.handle.nw {
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}   
.handle.ne {
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
}   
.handle.se {
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}       
.handle.sw {
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Now with jQuery (or pure js) it's a piece of cake to retrieve the position:

```
$(".handle.se").offset()
```

Comment: Ha! Brilliant. I've spent hours trying to do the math on this. Finally gave up and looked to SO. Your answer is simple and creative.

Comment: Just wanted to add that I am currently using this technique and it works perfectly! Why do the work yourself if the browser will do it for you!

Comment: Note: doesn't work for arbitrary elements. Only works for transformed elements that have style position set explicitly to relative or absolute. Other wise your "handles" could end up rendered outside the bounds of their parent element.

Comment: @user2782001 you could use various methods to make sure each element is at the corner (i.e. a 0x0 container, then the 0x0 with a margin-left or margin-top of the width height  <containerdiv><0x0><topright margin-left:containerWidth></0x0><0x0><bottomright margin-left:containerWidth,margin-top:containerHeight></0x0> etc...
basically, you can offset the corners using `margin`, but you have contain the corners in an additional 0x0 div.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think that there is API for that. As well as there is no API to convert coordinates in HTML5 `<canvas>`. But there is a way to calculate coordinates manually. Here is a class from my `<canvas>` library which converts coordinates: https://github.com/enepomnyaschih/jwcanvas/blob/master/jwidget/public/jwcanvas/transform.js

You can use it as a template.

To initialize coordinate system, you should just instantiate an object of `JW.Canvas.Transform` class and apply method `complex`. After that, you can apply other transformations to coordinate system via `transform` method. Matrixes are:

- translate: [1, 0, 0, 1, x, y]
- scale: [x, 0, 0, y, 0, 0]
- rotate clockwise: [cos(a), sin(a), -sin(a), cos(a), 0, 0]
- skew along x: [1, 0, tan(a), 1, 0, 0]
- skew along y: [1, tan(a), 0, 1, 0, 0]

After that, you'll be able to convert coordinates via `convert` method. Use `back` method to calculate backwards convertion object.

Comment: Does it work for CSS3 transform3D matrix (rotateX, rotateY and perspective)?

Comment: In 3D, 4x4 matrix is used to represent the transformations, so there will be 12 meaning numbers instead of 6 for orthogonal transformations, with the fixed last line: [0, 0, 0, 1]. Translation, scaling, rotation and skewing transformations will have similar matrixes. Quick googling helps to find a matrix for perspective projection: [[1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1/d, 1]] (last line is meaning!)

Answer (score 4):

I recommend to you this site : http://www.useragentman.com/blog/2011/01/07/css3-matrix-transform-for-the-mathematically-challenged/ and in particular the section "Other Interesting Facts About Matrices"...

But as Egor Nepomnyaschih pointed out, you just have to implement the calculus for each transformation and to chain them.

I have implemented a jsFiddle based on your example : http://jsfiddle.net/pvS8X/3/ .

Just be careful : the origin is the middle of your figure! If your want to refer to the top, left corner, you have to set this is your CSS code :

```
transform-origin: 0 0;
```

cf. https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/CSS/transform-origin.

The main method are these one :

```
function skew(p, alpha, beta) {
    var tan_a = Math.tan(alpha * Math.PI / 180),
        tan_b = Math.tan(beta * Math.PI / 180),
        p_skewed = {};

    p_skewed.x = p.x + p.y * tan_a;
    p_skewed.y = p.x * tan_b + p.y;

    return p_skewed;
}


function rotate(p, theta) {
    var sin_th = Math.sin(theta * Math.PI / 180),
        cos_th = Math.cos(theta * Math.PI / 180),
        p_rot = {};

    p_rot.x = p.x * cos_th - p.y * sin_th;
    p_rot.y = p.x * sin_th + p.y * cos_th;

    return p_rot;
}


function scale(p, sx, sy) {
    var p_scaled = {};

    p_scaled.x = p.x * sx;
    p_scaled.y = p.y * sy;

    return p_scaled;
}
```

where p is an object on the form `{ x: <some_horizontal_pos>, y: <some_vertical_pos>}`.

Comment: I don't quite understand yet. What does this return exactly? And how can I retrieve the other 3 corners?

Comment: @Horen you just have to put the value in the 2 fields x and y and you will see the corresponding output... I have updated my fiddle in order to take coordinates relative to top-left instead of middle : http://jsfiddle.net/pvS8X/7/ .

Comment: Is it possible to add 3d css transform (rotateX/Y and perspective)?

Comment: That first link is just what I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As explained in https://stackoverflow.com/a/70696654/11769765, `getComputedStyle(A).transform` returns the final [transformation matrix](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/matrix)

```js
R.innerHTML = getComputedStyle(A).transform
```

```css
#A {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    display: inline-block;        
    background: pink;
    transform: skew(10deg, 30deg) rotate(30deg) scale(1, 2);
    transform-origin: 0 0;
}
#cross {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
    height: 10px;
    transform: translate(0, 45px);
    background: black;
}
#corner {
    position: absolute;
    width: 5px;
    height: 5px;
    transform: translate(95px, 0);
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="A">
<div id="cross"></div>
<div id="corner"></div>
</div>

<output id="R"></output>
```

For the demo it is `matrix(0.954189, 1, -0.694593, 1.1547, 0, 0)`. Then e.g. the corner `(x, y) = (100, 0)` becomes `(100*0.954189, 100*1) = (95.4189, 100)`.
One also has take into account `transform-origin` (which was reset above to `0 0`).

Answer (score -3):

You can find the new position of your element respective to the window using .getBoundingClientRect()